# Converting a list type to individual type in DEAP library

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, deap

I am using deap library to apply genetic algorithm (GA) in a problem. I am using tool.box to generate individuals (solutions) and population. Individuals have a type of list. In some generations of GA, I manually produce several solutions (with a type of list) and I want to add them to population. However, before adding, I need to convert their type from list to individual so that they get the fitness attribute.
This is a part of my codes:

```
creator.create("FitnessMin", base.Fitness, weights=(-1.0,))
creator.create("Individual", list, fitness=creator.FitnessMin)
.
.
.
toolbox.register("individual", create_Ind_Function, ...)
toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)
toolbox.register("evaluate",  Fitness_Function)
```

Could you please let me know any solution for this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has a simple solution. Before adding solutions to the population, `creator.Individual()` should be applied to produced solutions to convert their type from list to individual. For example, if we have `sol1` and `sol2` with list type, we need to use the following way to convert them to individual:

```
ind1 = creator.Individual(sol1)
ind2= creator.Individual(sol2)
```